# Binance signed api call nodejs 12 AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, https, aws-lambda, binance

Hi I'm trying to use the Binance futures api call https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade using AWS Lambda and nodejs 12 but am getting error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443` Here is my code

```
module.exports = {
  marketOrder: async function(https, req, crypto, apiKey, secretKey, symbol, side, quantity, timestamp) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey).digest("hex");
      const url = `https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order?symbol=${symbol}&type=MARKET&side=${side}&timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature}`;
      const options = {
        path: url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey,
        },
      };
      const httpRequest = https.request(options, (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        result.on('data', (data) => {
          resolve(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
        });
      });
      httpRequest.write(req.body);
      httpRequest.end();
    })
  }
}
```